# Firebird SQL index on multiple columns

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

This is for Firebird 2.5.

I have a table T with an index made of 2 columns, say ColA and ColB. If I'm doing :
`SELECT * FROM T WHERE ColA=...`, so the WHERE clause is only on column A, will Firebird put a default value for column ColB, and benefit of the index, or it cannot use at all this index?

A bit of context:
I'm doing a db upgrade. Here is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
     newid BIGINT NOT NULL,
     oldid BIGINT NOT NULL,
     anotherCol INT);

CREATE INDEX idx ON  user(oldid, anotherCol);
     
CREATE TABLE order(
     RefUser BIGINT);
```

order.RefUser were oldid and I need to change them to newid. I do it using this query:

```
UPDATE order o SET o.refuser = (SELECT u.newid FROM user u WHERE u.oldId = o.refuser);
```

At this point of time, oldid is still unique, but later on the uniqueness will only be guaranteed for (oldid, anotherCol), hence the index, and the creation of newid.

User table is a few million of records, order table is a few dozens of millions: this query takes more than an hour. I would like to see how to improve it (not keen on shutting down a critical service for that amount of time).

Comment: If there is an index on columns A and B in this order, then FB will use this index when WHERE contains conditions with A or with A and B simultaneously, but will not use the index if only B column present in WHERE clause.

Comment: @Andrej: yes index is on A, B, and only A is in my WHERE clause.. So from what you're saying Firebird will use the index... So no optimization from that side... Thanks a lot for this precise answer!

Comment: @SoyonsPrecis u could just make a test: PREPARE your query and read its execution PLAN - granted, whether that index would be used or not would be decided by Firebird according to the specific date in the table (aka index SELECTIVITY). But general rule is that compound indices might get used on any subset of its first columns, A or A&B or A&B&C, etc

Comment: For the query shown, you should consider using [`merge`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-merge.html) instead

Comment: @Mark: I didn't know about that MERGE stuff, so thanks for letting me know. I did try on a smaller table, however my query is still slightly better than the MERGE one (again, this is FB 2.5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the index statistics are up-to-date, or at least good enough for the optimizer, then Firebird can (and often will) use a multi-column index when not all columns are part of the where-clause. The only restriction is that it can only use it for the first columns (or the 'prefix' of the index).

So with

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON  user(oldid, anotherCol);
```

Firebird can use the index `idx` just fine for `where oldid = 'something'`, but not for `where anotherCol = 'something'`.

And no, Firebird does not *"put a default value for column [anotherCol]"*. It does a range scan on the index and returns all rows that have the matching `oldid` prefix.

Technically, Firebird creates index keys by combining the columns as described in [Firebird for the Database Expert: Episode 1 - Indexes](https://web.archive.org/web/20231015050240/https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_18), which means the value in the index is something like:

```
0<oldid> 1<anotherCol> : row_id
```

e.g. (simplified, as in real life Firebird also does a prefix compression)

```
0val1 1other1 : rowid1
0val1 1other2 : rowid4
0val1 1other3 : rowid6
0val2 1other1 : rowid2
...
```

When using `where oldid = 'val1'`, Firebird will search the index for all entries that start with `0val1 1` (as if it was doing a string search for `0val1 1%` on a single column). And in this case it will match rowid1, rowid4 and rowid6.

Although this works, if you query a lot on only `oldid`, it might be better to also create a single column index on `oldid` only, as this index will be smaller and therefor faster to traverse when searching for records. The downside of course is that more indices have a performance impact on inserts, updates and deletes.

See also [Concatenated Indexes](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys) on [Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/).

Comment: `the index statistics are up-to-date, or at least good enough for the optimizer` only the second part decides whether server would use it :-) While keeping statistics up to date is important, but decision is made comparing indexes selectivity as they are known. If data is out of date somehow - optimizer would still use it, because if it knew - it would just update it :-D